# Does this design represent circular dependency?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

Imagine this example (that may be run without any errors):

```
from random import uniform

class Car:    
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = position
        self.sensor = Sensor(id, self)

class Sensor:
    def __init__(self, id, carrier_car):
        self.id = id
        self.position = self.compute_position(carrier_car)

    def compute_position(self, carrier_car):
        return [carrier_car.position[0] + uniform(1,3), carrier_car.position[0] + uniform(2,4)]
        
car1 = Car([10,10])
print("This car's sensor coordinate is ({},{}).".format(car1.sensor.position[0], car1.sensor.position[1]))
```

**Question 1.**

Given the line `self.sensor = Sensor(id, self)`, I don't understand how this line runs without any problem. Isn't this circular dependency? (`self`, in the argument, is an object of `Car` which has not yet been completely created (initialized) at the point it is passed to the initializer of `Sensor`.)

**Question 2.**

If this a circular dependency, how can I resolve it?

Comment: The `Sensor` class doesn't have to exist until that code is executed, which doesn't happen until you create a `Car` object.  And since `Sensor` does not refer to a `Car`, there's no circular dependency anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self` object that is passed to `Sensor(id, self)` is an already existing `Car` instance, but it does not have a `sensor` attribute yet.

Since `Sensor` only requires the `position` attribute of the `carrier_car` object, this is not a problem, since it has already been created in the line `self.position = position`.

In any case, this design is a bit confusing. I would not pass a `Car` object to `Sensor`, but just a `position`, as this is all that `Sensor` needs to know about the car. This would also simplify the code:

```
from random import uniform

class Car:    
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = position
        self.sensor = Sensor(id, position)

class Sensor:
    def __init__(self, id, position):
        self.id = id
        self.position = self.compute_position(position)

    def compute_position(self, position):
        return [position[0] + uniform(1,3), position[0] + uniform(2,4)]
        
car1 = Car([10,10])
print("This car's sensor coordinate is ({},{}).".format(car1.sensor.position[0], car1.sensor.position[1]))
```

Comment: In my real (longer) code, `compute_position()` needs multiple properties of `Car`, and that's why I passed the full object rather than the single position to that function. Thanks for your explanations!